# What is a good Microbiology atlas for Bacteriology as online version?

Tags: bacteriology

I am looking for a online atlas for Bacteriology, the cost does not matter.
I have been searching SpringerLink, and Amazon but no good online version found.

**What is a good atlas for Bacteriology as a online version?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for? If you change the question or comment I can update my answer...

[NCBI's taxonomy site](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/taxonomyhome.html/) has a listing of bacteria.  [Encyclopedia of life](http://eol.org/) is also great.

Then there's [UCSC's microbial genome browser](http://microbes.ucsc.edu/).

[Biocyc](http://biocyc.org/) is  great reference for bacterial genes.  to get into E coli, which is the model bacterium there's [Port Eco](http://porteco.org/) featuring 130 E coli genomes.

Am Soc Micro has an excellent [E coli/ Salmonella site based on their classic reference](http://ecosal.org/) - you have to pay for access though.

Comment: Thank you very much! The http://eol.org/ is outstanding resource for the basic course of Microbiology.

Comment: Ah glad I could help you find what you wanted! :)